# Which UNIX utility do I use?

Tags: bash, unix, utility

I am working on a variety of projects that need a specific compilers. Fortunately, on the machine I'm working on, I am supplied with a command `module`, that makes swapping compilers easy e.g.

```
module unload PrgEnv-intel
module load PrgEnv-cray
```

or,

```
module swap PrgEnv-intel PrgEnv-cray
```

There's also a command, `module list`, which lists all the currently loaded modules. The output is roughly

```
Currently loaded modules:
1) module_foo/v2.3
2) module_bar/1.1.8
...
17) PrgEnv-pgi/5.2.40
```

or something to that effect. (The compiler isn't necessarily listed at position 17; it's just somewhere on that list.)

**My problem:** There are multiple possibilities for which compiler could be loaded at a given time. I want to write a script in each project's directory that takes the output of `module list`, finds the part of the list beginning with `PrgEnv` (e.g. `PrgEnv-xxx` for the xxx compiler, whichever one is currently loaded), then executes the command `module swap PrgEnv-xxx PrgEnv-cray` for say a project that requires the cray compiler.

The point here is that I can't load the cray compiler (say) unless I *un*load whichever compiler is currently loaded. I can access this information by examining the results of `module list`, but I'd rather just write a script that automates all of this.

Is this insane overkill? Perhaps, but I'm also currently trying to learn how to solve more generic problems with UNIX commands and I figure will be a good learning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $# = 1 ] || { echo "Usage: $0 PrgEnv-new" >&2; exit 1; }

new_module="${1:?}"

cur_module=$(module list | sed -n '/^[0-9]*) *\(PrgEnv-[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)\/.*/ s//\1/p')

if [ -z "$cur_module" ]
then module load "$new_module"
else if [ "$cur_module" != "$new_module" ]
then module swap "$cur_module" "$new_module"
else echo "Current module is $cur_module; so is requested module"
fi
```

That uses standard (prehistoric) `sed` notations and should work with any version.  The `-n` suppresses the normal 'echo' operation.  The pattern looks for digits followed by a `)` and spaces and `PrgEnv-` and an identifier followed by a `/` and junk.  It replaces all that with `PrgEnv-` and the identifier and prints the resulting line.  It could, perhaps should, quit after that (change `p` to `{ p; q; }`).

The following code tests whether there is a module loaded.  If not, it loads the new one.  If the new module is different from the current one, it swaps them.  If the new module is the same as the current one, it says so.

The first line checks that the script was called with one argument, printing a usage message if it wasn't.  The second captures the value in the argument, checking that it isn't empty (so somebody didn't get fancy and invoke `switch_env ''`, assuming the script is called `switch_env`).

Comment: Great, thanks! I thought `sed` might be the tool I was looking for...I'm still unfamiliar with `sed`, `grep`, and `awk`. Can you tell me what the last few characters in that line (`s//\1/p`) are doing?

Comment: The empty match part `s//` means 'match what the previous pattern matched', which it the big ugly regex containing `PrgEnv` etc.  The replacement `/\1/` means 'replace the matched pattern -- which matches the whole line -- with the remembered bit (inside `\(...\)`).  The `p` suffix means 'print'; the `-n` suppresses printing by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
module list | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d/ -f1 | grep ^PrgEnv | xargs module unload && module load PrgEnv-cray
```